# Template_locate () issue wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins

For redirecting template in my plugin file i used php and wordpress function and that works fine.

```
function wpc_template_chooser($wpc_template){
global $wp_query;
$wpc_plugindir = dirname(__FILE__);

$wpc_post_type = get_query_var('post_type');

if( $wpc_post_type == 'wpcproduct' ){
    return $wpc_plugindir . '/themefiles/single-wpcproduct.php';
}

if (is_tax('wpccategories')) {
    return $wpc_plugindir . '/themefiles/taxonomy-wpccategories.php';
}

if (is_tax('wpctags')) {
    return $wpc_plugindir . '/themefiles/taxonomy-wpctags.php';
}

return $wpc_template;
```

But when in other plugin i used OOP to locate template. It also works fine.
But to approach the results with OOP i used Template-locate(). 
Something like that

```
function kbe_template_chooser($template){

$template_path = apply_filters( 'kbe_template_path', 'wp_knowledgebase/' );

$find = array();
$file = '';

if ( is_single() && get_post_type() == 'kbe_knowledgebase' ) {

    $file   = 'single-kbe_knowledgebase.php';
    $find[] = $file;
    $find[] = $template_path . $file;

} elseif ( is_tax('kbe_taxonomy') || is_tax( 'kbe_tags') ) {

    $term   = get_queried_object();

    if ( is_tax( 'kbe_taxonomy' ) || is_tax( 'kbe_tags' ) ) {
        $file = 'taxonomy-' . $term->taxonomy . '.php';
    } else {
        $file = 'archive.php';
    }

    $find[] = 'taxonomy-' . $term->taxonomy . '-' . $term->slug . '.php';
    $find[] = $template_path . 'taxonomy-' . $term->taxonomy . '-' . $term->slug . '.php';
    $find[] = 'taxonomy-' . $term->taxonomy . '.php';
    $find[] = $template_path . 'taxonomy-' . $term->taxonomy . '.php';
    $find[] = $file;
    $find[] = $template_path . $file;

} elseif ( is_post_type_archive( 'kbe_knowledgebase' ) || is_page( get_option('kbe_archive_page_id' ) ) ) {

    $file   = 'archive-kbe_knowledgebase.php';
    $find[] = $file;
    $find[] = $template_path . $file;

}

if ( $file ) {
    $template       = locate_template( array_unique( $find ) );
    if ( ! $template ) {
        $template = trailingslashit( dirname(__FILE__) ) . 'template/' . $file;
    }
}

  return $template;
```

There is problem with locate template. When i use locate template in plugin it conflicts with the other plugins. Every plugin showing the same result of plugin  as in locate template i used.

Is there any solution ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out it myself.. 
the issue was with

```
elseif ( is_post_type_archive( 'kbe_knowledgebase' ) || is_page(    get_option('kbe_archive_page_id' ) ) ) {
```

this line .,.
i just change the one thing. that is

```
elseif ( is_post_type_archive( 'kbe_knowledgebase' ) || is_page( 'KBE_PAGE_TITLE' ) ) {
```

that's it.